# Refactoring a TGA image parser

Tags: c#

I have followed the TGA specs described [here](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/Dataformats/tga/) (the info at the end of the page is what this method is based on) and have written a method that takes a TGA file's pixel data section and creates a bitmap out of it.

It works, but the code looks sloppy. Particularly, when I'm actually reading the bytes. You'll notice that I do some sort of odd `foreach` loop in order to repeatly add the same bytes to my array.

Here's the method that reads the pixels. It returns an array of bytes representing the pixels.

Is there a way for me to re-write the inner loop in the `128` case to NOT use a foreach in order to set the same sequence of bytes to an array? I imagine I will find myself putting bytes into an array often and it would be nice to know other ways to do it.

```
private byte[] getImageType10()
{
    // header stores total bits per pixel
    int bytesPerPixel = header.bpp / 8; 
    int total = header.width * header.height * bytesPerPixel;

    // number of bytes we've read so far
    int count = 0;                      
    int repeat;
    byte packetHdr;
    int packetType;

    // temp storage
    byte[] bytes;                       
    byte[] pixData = new byte[total];

    while (count < total)
    {
        packetHdr = inFile.ReadByte();
        packetType = packetHdr & (1 << 7);

        // RLE packet
        if (packetType == 128)
        {
            // packet stores number of times following pixel is repeated
            repeat = (packetHdr & ~(1 << 7)) + 1;
            bytes = inFile.ReadBytes(bytesPerPixel);
            for (int j = 0; j < repeat; j++)
            {
                foreach (byte b in bytes)
                {
                    pixData[count] = b;
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        // raw packet
        else if (packetType == 0)
        {
            // packet stores number of pixels that follow
            repeat = ((packetHdr & ~(1 << 7)) + 1) * bytesPerPixel;
            for (int j = 0; j < repeat; j++)
            {
                pixData[count] = inFile.ReadByte();
                count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return pixData;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 128 case can be optimized as:

```
    if (packetType == 128) 
    { 
        // packet stores number of times following pixel is repeated 
        repeat = (packetHdr & ~(1 << 7)) + 1; 
        bytes = inFile.ReadBytes(bytesPerPixel);
        for (int j = 0; j < repeat; j++) 
        {
            bytes.CopyTo(pixData, count);
            count += bytes.Length;
        }
    }
```

The 0 case can be optimized as:

```
    if (packetType == 0) 
    { 
        // packet stores number of pixels that follow 
        repeat = ((packetHdr & ~(1 << 7)) + 1) * bytesPerPixel;
        bytes = inFile.ReadBytes(repeat);
        bytes.CopyTo(pixData, count);
        count += bytes.Length;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to look at what Array class provides! Though, guess I should check whether it's actually faster or not.

Comment: It really should be faster :)

Answer (score 3):

My answer is heavily based on that by @WouterH, so if you upvote me, then you must upvote Wouter twice. What I did is provided a "full" code listing, cleaned up some variable names and comments (many comments were removed after the proper variable names were used), added a class for the image header and added the placeholder for the error checking. I am not too happy with the magic constant `positiveMask` because I do not fully understand what it does. You could replace code contracts with exceptions in order to use fewer assemblies. You can speed the code up a bit by pre-computing some variables in the ImageHeader class once. Other improvements are possible, but we have not seen your entire code, so it is hard to tell. I would also split up this one file into two different ones - one per class.

```
namespace TGAImageParser
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
    using System.IO;

    // Using a class like this helps to avoid http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DataEnvy
    internal class TGAImageHeader
    {
        public const int BitsInByte = 8; // const is ok over readonly here since this will not change in the future, right?

        public readonly int BytesPerPixel;
        public readonly int Width;
        public readonly int Height;

        public TGAImageHeader(int bytesPerPixel, int width, int height)
        {
            // Check the inputs thoroughly here.
            Contract.Requires(width > 0, "Image must be at least one pixel wide."); // Or is it zero pixels wide?
            // ... and so on.

            this.BytesPerPixel = bytesPerPixel;
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;
        }

        public int BitsPerPixel
        {
            get
            {
                return this.BytesPerPixel * BitsInByte;
            }
        }

        // If this gets called often, then pre-compute it once.
        public int TotalBytes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.BytesPerPixel * this.TotalPixels;
            }
        }

        // If this gets called often, then pre-compute it once.
        public int TotalPixels
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Width * this.Height;
            }
        }
    }

    public class TGAImageParser
    {
        public const int RLEPacketType = 128;
        public const int RawPacketType = 0;

        private const byte positiveMask = 1 << 7; // TODO: Come up with a better name! What does it do?

        public static byte[] GetImageType10Bytes(BinaryReader inFile, TGAImageHeader imageHeader)
        {
            int numBytesReadSoFar = 0;
            int numTimesPixelIsRepeated;
            byte packetHeaderByte;
            int packetType;

            byte[] tempStorageBuffer;
            byte[] pixData = new byte[imageHeader.TotalBytes];

            while (numBytesReadSoFar < imageHeader.TotalBytes)
            {
                packetHeaderByte = inFile.ReadByte();
                packetType = packetHeaderByte & positiveMask;

                if (packetType == RLEPacketType)
                {
                    numTimesPixelIsRepeated = (packetHeaderByte & ~positiveMask) + 1;
                    tempStorageBuffer = inFile.ReadBytes(imageHeader.BytesPerPixel);
                    for (int i = 0; i < numTimesPixelIsRepeated; i++)
                    {
                        tempStorageBuffer.CopyTo(pixData, numBytesReadSoFar);
                        numBytesReadSoFar += tempStorageBuffer.Length;
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                if (packetType == RawPacketType)
                {
                    numTimesPixelIsRepeated = ((packetHeaderByte & ~positiveMask) + 1) * imageHeader.BytesPerPixel;
                    tempStorageBuffer = inFile.ReadBytes(numTimesPixelIsRepeated);
                    tempStorageBuffer.CopyTo(pixData, numBytesReadSoFar);
                    numBytesReadSoFar += tempStorageBuffer.Length;

                    continue;
                }

                // TODO: report an error here?
            }

            return pixData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I defined a separate header class because it seemed like something nice to do, but I wasn't sure how to justify it. The `positiveMask` is just used because the format uses the high-order bit to identify the packet type and the rest of the bits to store a number. I didn't think about setting it as a const though and that would avoid having to compute it again and again when it's always the same value.

Comment: I see ... this should execute a bit faster but it is harder to understand. I like using something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431732/checking-if-a-bit-is-set-or-not
Since there is only one bit that drives this, you do not need to have two separate if statements. You could do `if(cond) { <doSmthIfYes> return;} <doSmthIfNo>` instead of `if (...) {...} else {...}` but it is just a matter of preference; either one will execute fast enough.